# Can EF Core map a property to a non-id column from another table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

```
Table1:
int Id
string Name
```

```
Table2:
int Id
string X
```

Is it possible to have an entity like this?

```
class MyEntity {
   int Id { get; } //  Table1's
   string Name { get; }
   string X { get; } 
}
```

I do NOT want to have a separate entity for Table2.

**Explanation**:

The reason why I don't want a separate entity is because I'm trying to achieve **encapsulation**.

The Table1.**Name** and Table2.**X** go **hand in hand** from a business rule point of view, the properties need to be kept in "sync". One one is updated, so is the other one, based on some value logic.

With a separate entity class (Table2), it would require having the Table2.X property **public** so that it can be set from MyEntity entity class. Instead, I would like to have the X property in the MyEntity class, in order to set both the Name and X properties together and keep them in sync.

I think MyEntity is an aggregate.

Comment: Any reasonable notice why it is needed?

Comment: Entity splitting is on the road map for EF core 7.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Please see my edit, I tried to explain why.

Comment: @GertArnold I cannot see how the entity splitting would help. I think my situation is the opposite, I need two tables into one entity. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @WriteEatSleepRepeat, I know only one way how to do something similar - TPT(Table-per-Type). But here you need hierarchy [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv If I understand it correctly, TPT works if you have a shared primary key, which in the example there is the `BlogId`. I cannot see how would it work in my case.

Comment: Two tables into one entity is entity splitting. The entity is "split up" into multiple tables.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. How can I implement "entity splitting" in EF Core?

Comment: @GertArnold I think your suggestion of "entity splitting" cannot be implemented in EF Core

Comment: I searched a lot but I'm unable to find information on this. I doubt I am the only one with this problem.

Comment: Well, I said it's on the roadmap.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. Is there an interim solution? How is everyone doing it today?